# Update Foreign-key Related Instance on Post Request

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a system where a user can subscribe to a company. For that I have to implement the following flow:

1. User registers
2. User klicks on a button to subscribe to a company
3. User has to enter a code (every company has a secret code. By possession the user proves that he is somewhat related to the company)
4. User is subscribed

For this, I have to implement an API endpoint that receives the code by the user (the user is authenticated at this point).

**It is shameful, but I am lost:** I am thinking of implementing a view like this.

```
class RegisterUserToCustomer(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Obviously, I have to:

1. Receive the code from the user via POST method
2. Search the database and figure out, if the code corresponds to any company
3. Edit the ForeignKey field on the user and link it to the company

But where would I implement this logic. With my limited experience I see three possibilities:

1. Call `serializer.save()` and write a custom `create()` method (but I don't want to create anything so this seems like bad practice
2. Implement this logic in the view, but I want to access the code from the `validated_data` (this seems like a problem?)
3. Can I write a custom `save()` method for the serializer? Are there any examples for a custom `save()` method since the original drf `save()` method contains a lot of validation logic.

Obviously I don't expect you guys to write the whole code for me, but maybe someone has somewhat of a blueprint of how and where to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to do this:

1. Create a field **company_code** in **Customer** table and make that
   field as **Foreign key**.
2. Create a Serializer with that foreign key field.
3. Create a viewset or generic views to expect that field from Post method as **Id** of the Company. Use `save()` method to store foreign key.

This scenarios is only for Subscribe one organisation, if you're able to subscribe multiple organisation make that field as **ManytoMany** field.

Refer the code sample,

**Models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    # customer related field
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'organization', )
```

**Views.py**

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
```

**Request data(POST Json)**

```
{
     "name": "test", 
     "organization": "id-of company"
}
```